# Strange behaviour of ObservedObject in SwiftUI when using Timer

Tags: swiftui

In the following program, Bar's initializer is called for each timer event.  Does anyone know the reason of this problem?

This problem happens in both simulators and real devices iOS 13.5. I tested this on Xcode 11.5.

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Foo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: Int
    
    init() {
        print("init")
        self.value = 10
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (_) in
            self.value += 1
        }
    }
}

class Bar: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: Int
    
    init() {
        print("Bar")
        self.value = 100
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var foo: Foo
    @ObservedObject var bar = Bar()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(foo.value)")
            Text("\(bar.value)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var foo: Foo

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(foo.value)")
            FirstView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time `Foo`, being an `ObservedObject`, publishes a change, it causes the views that "observe" it to re-render their `body`

`Foo` is observed in `ContentView`, so a change in `Foo` makes it re-compute its `body`:

```
VStack {
    Text("\(foo.value)")
    FirstView()
}
```

This calls `FirstView()`, which in turn calls `Bar()`.